# Prevent renderUI from updating all inputs

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Friends,
For some reason I have to render ui in a dynamic way (different GUI for different users) and got into a problem that I somehow cannot overcome no matter what. Tried isolating, reactivity, updates and all failed me. Perhaps you have some idea how to resolve it (or you might be of an opinion that trying to get it into render ui is absolutely stupid - hopefully not as it is already massive app). So first an example that works without any issues (a watered down representation of the issue, not the real app)

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput("cyl","cyl",unique(mtcars$cyl)),
selectInput("mpg","mpg","")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 mpg<- reactive({unique(mtcars%>%dplyr::filter(cyl==input$cyl)%>%select(mpg))})
 observeEvent(input$cyl,{updateSelectInput(session,"mpg", choices = mpg())})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Works without any glitches, you update the top list and it narrows down the bottom one
But in the render ui case a change of the first list causes update of the entire ui and consequently changes the top list to the first position in choices negating your choice

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- uiOutput("myUI")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myUI<-renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      selectInput("cyl","cyl",unique(mtcars$cyl)),
      selectInput("mpg","mpg",mpg()))
  })

  mpg<- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$cyl))
    unique(mtcars%>%dplyr::filter(cyl==input$cyl)%>%select(mpg))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I prevent entire UI from rebuilding? In this trivial example it is boiled down to 2 inputs but in the application it is a big leaflet map that should be updated by change to any of several inputs - rather tricky to store previously selected values and re-select them after refresh, but maybe it is the only way

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you have ended up with circular reactivity logic as a result of `ui <- uiOutput("myUI")`. Basically the UI is re-generated whenever the UI is updated. Here's how `renderUI` can be used in this case -

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("cyl","cyl",unique(mtcars$cyl)),
  uiOutput("select_mpg")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mpg <- reactive({
    req(input$cyl)
    m <- mtcars %>% dplyr::filter(cyl == input$cyl)
    unique(m$mpg)
  })

  output$select_mpg <- renderUI({
    selectInput("mpg","mpg",mpg())
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note that I have made some other changes to get the app working correctly and make the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you, but that's not an answer, you basically repeated what I wrote in the first example as working. Anything will work if you keep it in ui part, the question was how to make it working if you move entire ui rendering to server like in the second example

Answer (score 0):

sorry for bothering you but it was too easy, should have spotted it immediately
I can just render ui inside ui like

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- uiOutput("myUI")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myUI<-renderUI({
    fluidPage(
      selectInput("cyl","cyl",unique(mtcars$cyl)),
      uiOutput("xmpg")
      )
  })

  output$xmpg<-renderUI({selectInput("mpg","mpg",mpg())})

  mpg<- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$cyl))
    unique(mtcars%>%dplyr::filter(cyl==input$cyl)%>%select(mpg))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

then any calls do not re-render the top level ui, just the ui in question